# More than one expression parsed error ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df.test <- data.frame(
id = c("EIF3H", "USP9X", "USP44", "USP51", "USP15", 
       "USP48", "USP47", "USP43", "USPL1", "UCHL5", "USP50", "USP7", 
       "UCHL1", "USP11", "USP26", "PAN2", "VCPIP1", "USP46", "USP29", 
       "USP22", "USP49", "ZRANB1", "OTUD4", "OTUD7B", "USP54", "PSMD14", 
       "USP20", "USP6", "OTUD3", "USP39", "UCHL3", "USP19", "USP21", 
       "USP30", "TNFAIP3", "USP17L2", "USP32", "JOSD2", "PSMD7", "ATXN3L", 
       "SENP2", "STAMBPL1", "USP37", "USP35", "USP3", "ALG13", "USP45", 
       "Control", "USP9Y", "ATXN3", "OTUD6A", "USP42", "USP12", "MPND", 
       "USP40", "OTUD1", "USP31", "USP8", "USP13", "USP53", "USP34", 
       "USP17L5", "MYSM1", "USP36", "OTUD7A", "USP10", "USP2", "USP18", 
       "OTUB1", "EIF3F", "USP1", "USP14", "COPS5", "USP24", "USP4", 
       "CYLD", "COPS6", "STAMBP", "USP5", "OTUD6B", "BAP1", "USP25", 
       "YOD1", "USP28", "USP38", "USP41", "JOSD1", "UCK2", "USP16", 
       "USP27X", "BRCC3", "USP33", "OTUD5", "OTUB2"),
log.score = c(4.22265293851218, 3.03983376346562, 
              2.4139305569695, 2.32586482009754, 2.30391458369018, 2.19017103893211, 
              2.10803347738743, 2.10011933499842, 1.82596928196197, 1.79890343496053, 
              1.78330640083025, 1.58384231036782, 1.4480988629484, 1.4331502122056, 
              1.41965675282741, 1.37552194849409, 1.37548070593268, 1.3126672736385, 
              1.27123241483349, 1.25213781606166, 1.1643918571801, 1.14738583497561, 
              1.0423927129399, 1.03157776352028, 1.0279685056071, 0.953426802337995, 
              0.94104282122269, 0.929925173732472, 0.886424283199432, 0.886123467368948, 
              0.815961921373111, 0.811437095842094, 0.767054687254773, 
              0.754314635766764, 0.750654863646671, 0.728646377897516, 
              0.707899061519581, 0.703532261199885, 0.692546751828376, 
              0.684554481775416, 0.652104306506768, 0.642046105413661, 
              0.630116510664521, 0.62908000782908, 0.619354680809075, 0.614876544107784, 
              0.61293067306798, 0.606898831140113, 0.603504247802433, 0.578642901486857, 
              0.576246380387172, 0.549612309171809, 0.53101794103743, 0.513442014568548, 
              0.506304999011214, 0.492144128304169, 0.462596515841992, 
              0.454185884038717, 0.450163300207299, 0.434529992991809, 
              0.429725658566606, 0.42864060724616, 0.419896514762075, 0.409715596281838, 
              0.365946146577929, 0.363963683646553, 0.357614629472314, 
              0.352851847129221, 0.343470593766502, 0.313051079788499, 
              0.304614649499993, 0.291604597354374, 0.287030586811975, 
              0.272263598289704, 0.27175988000523, 0.265200170411153, 0.264528852761016, 
              0.244704590019742, 0.179680291853473, 0.154102353851514, 
              0.147800680553723, 0.127575655021633, 0.126051956011554, 
              0.1207205737776, 0.118712371231544, 0.11046860245595, 0.0939775902962627, 
              0.0673791277640148, 0.066320409857141, 0.0582650179118847, 
              0.0548860857591892, 0.0374554663486737, 0.0147532091971383, 
              0.0134163514896924),
neg.rank = 1:94)
```

From this data frame I made this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- "neg.rank"
p <- ggplot(df.test, aes_string(x = x, y = df.test$log.score)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I want to add labels to the top10 ids and I tried the following:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
p + geom_label_repel(data = df.test[df.test[[x]] %in% 1:10, ], aes_string(x = x, y = df$log.score, label = df.test$id))
```

But this gives me a `More than one expression parsed` error:

```
More than one expression parsed
Backtrace:
    █
 1. ├─ggrepel::geom_label_repel(...)
 2. │ └─ggplot2::layer(...)
 3. └─ggplot2::aes_string(x = x, y = df$log.score, label = df.test$id)
 4.   └─base::lapply(...)
 5.     └─ggplot2:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 6.       └─rlang::parse_expr(x)
```

I have no clue what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as you are inserting the vectors directly into your `aes_string`.

If you want yours to be working you need to be strict with your `aes_string` and really should only use strings:

```
p + 
  geom_label_repel(
    data = df.test[df.test[[x]] %in% 1:10, ], 
    aes_string(x = x, y = "log.score", label = "id"),
    )
```

I also added a "cleaner" solution. I changed your subsetting logic to use dplyr, as you are already loading the package anyway and changed all your `aes_string()` to `aes()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df.test, aes(x = neg.rank, y = log.score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = df.test %>% slice_min(neg.rank, n = 10), 
    aes(label = id),
    max.overlaps = 10,
    xlim = c(10, NA),
    ylim = c(3, NA),
    direction = "x"
  )
```

[image: Sample Image]

Cheers
Hannes